# Prevent double matches on self referencing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, self-join

Is there a quick and simple way in SQL to accomplish this, I have drawn up a long way to prevent this, by doing a "nested" self reference. Is there a simpler way?

Issue:

> When you are looking for similarities in table column you get [ID1, ID2] and [ID2, ID1] when you really only want one of them.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table t1
INNER JOIN Table t2 ON t1.col = t2.col
WHERE t1.id <> t2.id
```

Result:

| t1.id | t2.id | t1.col | t2.col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | sushi | sushi |
| 3 | 1 | sushi | sushi |
| 2 | 4 | taco | taco |
| 4 | 2 | taco | taco |

Desired result:

| t1.id | t2.id | t1.col | t2.col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | sushi | sushi |
| 2 | 4 | taco | taco |

Answer (score 4):

```
where t1.id < t2.id
```

It's that simple.

Comment: Oh you're so right, I feel dumb. Well if anyone else doesn't see that staring them in face as well, they will have a solution. XD

Comment: Or equally using `>`

Comment: If you use this answer then you may loose some data. Because it is situation then there is data in tables with t1.id > t2.id only case. And you dont select such data.

Comment: @RomaRuzich - look again. This is about joining a table with itself. Any pair of rows which match the other conditions will appear twice - once where the ids are in one order and once where the ids are in the opposite order. One of those will match the `<` condition and the other is precisely the duplicate results which we desire to suppress.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yep, It is my mistake. You are right. It passed behind me that table is joined with itself.